# How can I print the index corresponding to the selected value in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, printing, iteration

I want to be able to print the index of the maximum value found during my for loop.

I am able to find the  maximum value but not the corresponding index. It always gives me the last line index as output.

```
    with open(fname) as infile:
        largest = None
        index = 0
        lines = infile.readlines()[19:]
        for line in lines:  
            line.replace("\n", '') 
            case = line.split()
            test = float(case[3])
            if largest is None or test > largest:
            largest = test
            index += 1
     print(largest, index)
```

Comment: You need to save the index at the point when the larger value is found, the same way you save the value when it's larger than the previous largest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't keeping track of the largest index anywhere.

```py
with open(fname) as fh:
    largest, index = 0, 0 # start both of these at 0 so you don't have to check against None
    for i in range(19):
        next(fh) # consume up to the 19th line

    # use enumerate to track the line numbers, avoiding the need for 
    # manually incrementing a counter
    for i, line in enumerate(fh):
        line = line.strip().split() # strip will take off trailing newlines
        test = float(line[3])
        if test > largest:
            # track both values here
            largest, index = test, i

print(largest, index)
```